# How do I import a class from a file in python?

Tags: python, class, python-import

So hello again. I noticed I have not been asking the best python questions, but pray, bear with me. I have been working with classes to adopt the OOP method, even though I like it ***not***. So now I am trying to import a class from a file in the same directory as my main file, but it just gives me a ModuleNotFoundError (hate how long this name is). 
So here is the code from the main file:

```
import class_
ahmed = class_.Name('Ahmed')
ahmed.show()
```

And here is the code from the file I want to import:

```
class Name():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def show(self):
        print(self.name)
```

I know I made some dum dum mistake over here, but what is it?

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` in the same directory?

Comment: @CoryKramer Ummm...what's that?

Answer (score 0):

You should name your file which you want to import your code as `class_.py` and make sure it is in the same directory as the main file and this should work.

Comment: That's the exact problem! It's in the same directory, named after what you proposed, and yet it still gives me an error.

Comment: It worked for me. Check if you have accidentally capitalized or misspelled your file name